# Term for a word that refers to a gender of a species

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for a word, such as cow, ewe, or ram, that refers to a specific gender of a species?

For example:

- "I" is a pronoun
- "Spaniard" is a demonym
- A firefighter named Les McBurny would be an aptonym (or aptronym)
- "Doe" is a ____?

Comment: Interested to read if anyone has something for this. I've only ever heard/used "gender-specific noun."

Comment: I  think apples and oranges are being mixed here.

Comment: "Doe" is a deer, a female deer.  ;-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender

Comment: @jxh That is something completely different

Comment: I guess so, I saw *Genders are classes of nouns reflected in the behaviour of associated words.* and thought this was what you wanted.

Comment: @Lambie Apples and avarice perhaps, or oranges and orneriness. Apples and orange are both the same kind of thing, not a category error.

Comment: Gender noun seems to make sense.

Comment: If "I" is a pronoun, "Doe" is a noun. No?

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are all "single word" terms.  I can't find a "single word" term for what you ask.  I would say use "gendered", but that is an adjective for use referring to a single object noun - as in "Doe is a gendered noun" (word, deer, animal, example, or term would also work).

There is a single word "andronym", but that does not seem to be used as a general term for male animals like you are asking.  It also doesn't seem to have a feminine counterpart. Possibly it could be used as a neologism referring to a male animal name.